# Variable numbers of groups with Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, datagridview

I have a stream of data that I need to parse. The stream is sent line by line and takes the form:

```
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX
```

where the `X's` are hex characters, ie:

```
ID: 1F9  Data: AC 12 53 8F 14 11 FF 00 -> For example
```

The trick is that there are not always 8 data bytes, so any of these transmissions are also possible:

```
ID: XXX  Data: XX
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX XX 
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX XX XX 
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX XX XX XX 
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX XX XX XX XX 
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 
ID: XXX  Data: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX
```

I want to write a regular expression that can parse out the ID and the available data bytes from each transmission. I then need to store the bytes in an array to assign to a dataGridView.

How would the pattern be written to accomplish this? Is there a better way to assign the values to a row in a dataGridView than assigning to an array? Execution time needs to be optimized.

Thanks!

Comment: Multiple steps is fine - i.e. you don't need a single regular expression. Simply extract "XX XX XX" as a string and then convert that to a byte array (a separate question which has many duplicates).

Comment: If execution time is relevant, and the data is indeed in a fixed format like in your example, just use a loop and the string indexer `char c = myString[idx]` to get pairs of hex characters from the string and convert them into bytes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below. It first splits the input string and then selects the values into proper variables:

Note: you can use `split` variable directly, you ID is in index 1 and values start at 2. Ignore the first element as it contains an empty string.

```
String input = "ID: 1F9  Data: AC 12 53 8F 14 11 FF 00";
String pattern = @"ID:\s|\s\sData:\s|\s";

string[] split = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
string id = split[1]; // the first elements contains "" so ignore it
string[] values = new string[split.Length - 2];
for (int i = 2; i < split.Length; i++)
    values[i - 2] = split[i];
```